# How to convert a Jsoup Document to a W3C Document?

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup, apache-stanbol

I have build a Jsoup Document by parsing a in-house HTML page,

```
public Document newDocument(String path) throws IOException {

    Document doc = null;
    doc = Jsoup.connect(path).timeout(0).get();
            return new HtmlDocument<Document>(doc);
}
```

I would want to convert the Jsoup document to my `org.w3c.dom.Document`
I used an available library [DOMBuilder](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stanbol/trunk/enhancement-engines/htmlextractor/src/main/java/org/apache/stanbol/enhancer/engines/htmlextractor/impl/DOMBuilder.java) for this but when parsing I get `org.w3c.dom.Document` as null. I am unable to understand the problem, tried searching but couldnt find any answer.

Code to generate the W3C DOM Document :

```
Document jsoupDoc=factory.newDocument("http:localhost/testcases/test_2.html"));
org.w3c.dom.Document docu= DOMBuilder.jsoup2DOM(jsoupDoc);
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stanbol/trunk/enhancement-engines/htmlextractor/src/main/java/org/apache/stanbol/enhancer/engines/htmlextractor/impl/DOMBuilder.java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[To retrieve a jsoup document via HTTP](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url), make a call to `Jsoup.connect(...).get()`.  [To load a jsoup document locally](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file), make a call to `Jsoup.parse(new File("..."), "UTF-8")`.

The call to `DomBuilder` is correct.

When you say,

> I used an available library DOMBuilder for this but when parsing I
>   get org.w3c.dom.Document as null.

I think you mean, "I used an available library, DOMBuilder, for this but when printing the result, I get `[#document: null]`."  At least, that was the result I saw when I tried printing the `w3cDoc` object - but that doesn't mean the object is null.  I was able to traverse the document by making calls to `getDocumentElement` and `getChildNodes`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document jsoupDoc = null;

    try {
        jsoupDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802445").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc= DOMBuilder.jsoup2DOM(jsoupDoc);
    Element e = w3cDoc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList childNodes = e.getChildNodes();
    Node n = childNodes.item(2);
    System.out.println(n.getNodeName());
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Alternatively, Jsoup provides the W3CDom class with the method [`fromJsoup`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/W3CDom.html#fromJsoup(org.jsoup.nodes.Document)). This method transforms a Jsoup Document into a W3C document.

```
Document jsoupDoc = ...
W3CDom w3cDom = new W3CDom();
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = w3cDom.fromJsoup(jsoupDoc);
```

**UPDATE:**

- **Since 1.10.3** W3CDom is [no longer experimental](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/b6dda00bc19f6d3bc4009a6b9a4a932de9640bd4#diff-3a68878e35244e79b765c49ff7f50225).
- **Up to Jsoup 1.10.2** W3CDom class is still experimental.